TDATA / session + json telethon telegram HOW?
i want to make a soft for manage telegram accounts. right now i have a TDATA file of account but everyone told me that i needed a session + json for work with telethon. i search and know that session + json i cant convert from TDATA but there is a high chance that the account will be banned when i creating a session (just read it on forums). So i wanna ask, where else i cant export session + json? thank you!
i try convert session + json from TDATA with telethon and used public api ID and HASH

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I'm not sure if this question belongs here, but converting from tdata to session or vise versa usually results in instant ban or a decrease on account score (quality). The best approach is to create the session file directly from the sms provider (either real or virtual) or try creating the session file manually by receiving the code via the tdata ( do not use libraries that convert them automatically). Telegram API is so strict when dealing with automation at any level.

hey!
yes, when i try convert from tdata to sessioan via pyrogram i get banned!
maybe you know scripts or something else to try get session + js from sms? the sim is real, not virtual. or how to creat it manually from sms?
i cant undestand where i cant create a session realy
